# Parse Array of JSON objects in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I am wondering how can I parse Array of JSON objects in NodeJS?

I want to post JSON array to the server, and be able to use the received array as a regualar JavaScript array.

Thanks in advance.

This is my front-end part that I am converting Array to String using stringify function

```
document.getElementById("sendJson").addEventListener("click", function () {
    $.post("/echo", JSON.stringify(QuestionsArray), function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
})
```

This my back-end part that I am trying to convert Array of JSON object to Array

```
app.post('/echo', function (req, res) {
    var Array = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.toString()));
    res.end(Array[0]["QuestionText"].toString());
});
```

This is Array that I am trying to sent to the server:

```
[  
   {  
      "QuestionText":"What is your Name",
      "QuestionType":1
   },
   {  
      "QuestionText":"Where are you from",
      "QuestionType":2,
      "ChoiceList":[  
         "US",
         "UK"
      ]
   },
   {  
      "QuestionText":"Are you married",
      "QuestionType":3,
      "ChoiceList":[  
         "Yes",
         "No"
      ]
   }
]
```

[Here is the source code](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/j3yajkjwnnb5576/AACdKlCqutiUongcw_W-NfJda?dl=0)

Comment: If you are already sending a stringified array (why would you do that in the first place), why do you stringify it on the server again?

Comment: Without stringify in NodeJS part I get exception.  http://s1.postimg.org/v2urhx0kf/Capture.png

Comment: You need to use bodyparser middleware and just post the array without stringifying.

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin Please Help man, I am stuck for days on this.

Comment: `req.body` could work, and remove over complexities of parsing and stringifying

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your `app.js`:

```
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
...
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

Then you can just use `req.body` to get the posted values:

```
app.post('/echo', function (req, res) {
    var Array = req.body.data;
    res.end(Array[0]["QuestionText"].toString());
});
```

In front-end, don't do any stringifying:

```
$.post("/echo", {data: QuestionsArray}, function (data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: thankyou so much. I suspected it had something to do with the bodyParser. But wouldn't have found it in a week

Answer (score 4):

I'll try to explain this. First of all, you are crating a json string on the client.

```
JSON.stringify(QuestionsArray)
```

Then on the server, you are doing the same again:

```
JSON.stringify(req.toString()) // this is not needed
```

Then you parse the double stringifyed json string to a javascript object:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.toString()))
```

So now you actually have to parse it twice :). If you just stringify it on the server as you are now, and just call:

```
var arr = JSON.parse(req.toString());
```

You will get a javascript object that you can access like this:

```
res.end(arr[0].QuestionText.toString());
```

Have a look at this jsFiddle and open your developer tools. Look at the console when it runs and you will see where the problem is: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lse4wz4g/2/)

Answer (score 2):

You may actually send the JSON directly to server.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/echo",
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(QuestionsArray),
        processData: false,
        contentType: 'application/json'
    }).success(function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
```

And in node.js, use `bodyParser.json` to get it back.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({}));

app.post('/echo', function (req, res) {
    var array = req.body;
    res.end(array[0]["QuestionText"].toString());
});
```

*By the way, do not use `Array` as variable name because `Array` represent the `Array` class used by JavaScript and your code has overwritten it.*