# how to loop JSON array in nodeJS

Tags: node.js

How do I loop below JSON array in node JS??

```
[
    {
        "po_number": "PO1001",
        "product_id": "PD1001",
        "message": "Exists",
        "timestamp": "2016-05-01 10:33:02,123"
    },
    {
        "po_number": "PO1002",
        "product_id": "PD1002",
        "message": "Does not exist",
        "timestamp": "2016-05-01 10:33:03,432"
    }
]
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: where do you want to pass?

Comment: @HemantRajpoot I think he means parse.

Comment: did you try JSON.parse?

Comment: @user1125829 Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28707836/parse-array-of-json-objects-in-nodejs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var jsonParsed = JSON.parse(json);

Answer (score -2):

Below is the answer.

```
var resjson = respBody;
resjson.forEach(function(table) {
 var ponum = table.po_number;
});
```

Comment: either your question is wrong . I see your answer , it means how can i iterate over json object . If that is the question change it . Parse means what @minil said.

Comment: I had respbody json array in the question. With my answer I am able to parse the respbody json array and able to fetch fields like po_number using node js..

Comment: your answers shows that json is already parsed and you are just looping it to fetch index data.

Comment: yes. question is changed to loop instead of parse. Thanks.