# How parse the json arraylist in node.js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

i want to parse the following kind of data in the node js in order to perform operations on them.
the data :-

```
{"orderSummary":[ {
      "name":"Wine",
      "ProductPrice":"500",
      "ProductQuantity":"2",
      "ProductCost":"1000",
      "SellerId":"2"

   },{
      "name":"Whisky",
      "ProductPrice":"500",
      "ProductQuantity":"2",
      "ProductCost":"1000",
      "SellerId":"2"

   }]
}
```

here is my code snippet which iam using to parse the data :-

```
router.post('/createorder',function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);
     var data=req.body;
    var obj=JSON.parse(data);
    res.send(obj);
});
```

can anybody tell me what i can do besides looping (as i will implement it ) in order to parse the data and perform operations on it ?

Comment: i have gone through this but still i'm unable to find exact answer as my data is coming from an app as key value par showing in the input data

Comment: @atulkumar Please, be more clear about what are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: It depends on what parsing an operations you want to do... Be concrete.

Comment: i want to access the elements and store it in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{"orderSummary":[ {
  "name":"Wine",
  "ProductPrice":"500",
  "ProductQuantity":"2",
  "ProductCost":"1000",
  "SellerId":"2"

},{
  "name":"Whisky",
  "ProductPrice":"500",
  "ProductQuantity":"2",
  "ProductCost":"1000",
  "SellerId":"2"

}]
}
```

Assuming this json data is in body
   so just store in var
    var data=req.body.orderSummary
now iterate through it.
Thats the best way as you have json data.So you need to implement it.

Comment: i have tried that and iam getting the following error " SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0"

Comment: var data=req.body.orderSummary ;
for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
 console.log(data[i]);
}; // this code is working try it

Comment: It works for you?

Comment: Please upvote my answer.

Comment: already did that

Comment: Please use this link *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28707836/parse-array-of-json-objects-in-nodejs*