# Parsing arrays in req.body in node js express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, swagger, hyperledger

I am getting an array in request body like :

```
[

{
   "month" : "JUL",
   "year" :"2018"
},
{
   "month" : "JAN",
   "year" :"2018"
},
{
   "month" : "MAR",
   "year" :"2018"
}
    ]
```

This input has two parameters (month:enum and year:string).

I need to loop through this array and call the chaincode and finally send the response . I have done the following :

```
     for(var i=0; i<req.body.length; i++) {
                    var month = req.body[i].month;
                    var year = req.body[i].year;
                    var monthYear = month + year;
    key = monthYear + "_new";
        console.log("Key is ", key);
            var request = {
            //targets: let default to the peer assigned to the client
            chaincodeId: 'abc',
            fcn: 'getTransactionsByKey',
            args: [key]

//Calling chaincode smartcontract
return channel.queryByChaincode(request);
}
```

but the response is coming correct if I pass only one input parameter . If I pass two values in input , the 2nd value result overrides the first one . Any help on how can I get response for all the list of inputs with the overlapping part.

Also , I need to sort the input values before calling the chaincode , like if I get Feb Mar Jan in the input , I should sort it as Jan Feb Mar and then run the for loop.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
Thanks.

Comment: What exactly you means by parsing, some kind of string manipulation or what ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse Array of JSON objects in NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28707836/parse-array-of-json-objects-in-nodejs)

Comment: Can you `console.log(req.body.transaction)` and see is that what you want

Answer (score 2):

You can use `body-parser` in your `app.js` like this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ 
     extended: true 
}));
```

Let's say you are receiving array in the post request body with the key: `users` you will parse it like this:

```
req.body.users
```

(It contains the users array)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get the value from the key ?

```
for (var key in req.body) {
  if (req.body.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    let value = req.body[key];
    console.log( `value for ${key} is ${value}` )
  }
}
```